# whether to use php or javascript method for redirecting a page

Tags: javascript, php, html, header

Whenever I user php header("Location: index.php"), most of time then it does not work. It exactly DOES NOT work without any error nor any run-time fatal error. I don't use any echoing nor I keep empty lines prior to `header()` call. I double check everthing, but it does not work.

Now, I user JS solution. I write a function that gets the param, store it in an immediately created `<input>` field and the using Javascript in the same function, I get the value out of input and assign it to `window.location.href= value;` which then finalizes the redirection. Is my method reliable and good?
My function seems like this:

```
function redirect($address)
{
?>
<input id='this_address' value="<?php echo $address; ?>" />
window.location.href = document.getElementById("this_address").value;
<?php
```

}

Comment: When you send the `Location` header, are you _also_ [sending a `3xx` response status?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection)

Comment: Enable `error_reporting` to see [when it fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php). And the Javascript workaround is just that, a workaround.

Comment: Then JavaScript option won't work on a client that has JavaScript switched off.  A location header is probably the best option for a redirect on load and it is worth finding out why it is not working for you.

Comment: Stick with PHP.   If you post your actual redirect code (and obviously relevant nearby code), we can take a look and see if there might be a reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes that is why I have been dubious on using Javascripts. as @Sagarwalla has suggested there might be problems with my session assignment

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your index.php is in the same directory as the scripts that calls redirect or vice versa...?

If not try `header("location:../../index.php");`

Comment: ok well could you please add the actual php code rather than telling us whats not working.....there might be issues before the scripts hits header location .... remember use php tags supported by server ie <?php ?> or <? ?>

Answer (score 0):

Setting and cookies or session variables will cause issues with a redirect. It has to be sent before any output or exchange with the server and the client. Check your browser log for any errors too. It might be helpful in determining why you are not achieving the result you want.

You could also implement both methods, but it would be more useful to find out why your PHP redirect is not effective.

Comment: then how to set sessions when we need to ?

Answer (score 0):

If u can't able to find out the solution for php header prob, Just add the below code at the top of the page. This is not the perfect way, but we can use this...

```
ob_start();
```

Comment: I think ob_start() is usually inaccessible in Hosted sites

Comment: I don't think soo.. used so many times, didn't face any prob.. ok.. Just try perfect Header function .   header('Location: index.php');

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `Response.Redirect "../../index.php"` to redirect to another page.